# How to get the result of a textfield in django?

Tags: python, django

i am making a python editor, and i have a model called `NewJax`. In this model, i have a field called `space`.

The `space` field executes the python code i typed in there.

for example, if i did `print('hello')` in the `space` field, it should take me to a detail page, and return the result. Which is `hello`.

but when it takes me to the details page for now, it results in `None`.

Could you someone please let me know, how this should execute?

`models.py`

```py
class NewJax(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=140)
    space = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_created']
        verbose_name_plural = "New Jax"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

`forms.py`

```py
class CreateNewJaxForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewJax
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'space')

        widgets = {
            "title": forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                   'class': 'form-control',
                   'placeholder': 'name your jax'
                }
            ),
            'description': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'add a brief description for jax',
                    'rows': 4,
                }
            ),
            'space': forms.Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                }
            )
        }
```

`views.py`

```py
def create_new_jax(request):
    if request.user.username == "Assasinator":
        logout(request)
        return redirect('banned_user')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewJaxForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            description = form.cleaned_data.get('description')
            space = form.cleaned_data.get('space')

            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.title = title
            obj.description = description
            obj.space = space
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()

            return redirect('/result/' + str(title) + '/')
        else:
            form = CreateNewJaxForm()
    else:
        form = CreateNewJaxForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "editor/jax_create.html", context)


@login_required
def result(request, title):
    res = get_object_or_404(NewJax, title=title)
    for x in NewJax.objects.all():
        co_res = exec(x.space)
    context = {
        "res": res,
        "co_res": co_res,
    }
    return render(request, "editor/run_result.html", context)
```

So these are the necessary files. IF someone needs more files or info. Please comment.

in the HTML files, there are just the `form` for it, and the `{{ result }}`. Please let me know if you need those too.

So please let me know how to return the result in the `result` view.

Thanks!

Comment: `exec` simply executes given code and returns `None`. Although this can be easily solved I would advice you not to go about things this way. You are running arbitrary code on your server this way! It only takes one malicious person  to mess up your server and crash it / steal data and many more possibilities. All such platforms you find online that execute your code do this an isolated environment.

Comment: thanks for info. So do you have any other alternate other than `exec`? Like something to execute the user's code?

Comment: Make a Sandbox to execute the users code. You would find many solutions using Docker if you search on the internet. Never really did this so can't give anymore advice.

Comment: uh, i don't understand what you mean by sandbox. Can you give me some code? Thanks! Also, if you don' t know, could you ask someone you **know**?

Comment: _"In computer security, a sandbox is a security mechanism for separating running programs, usually in an effort to mitigate system failures and/or software vulnerabilities from spreading. It is often used to execute untested or untrusted programs or code, possibly from unverified or untrusted third parties, suppliers, users or websites, without risking harm to the host machine or operating system."_ - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security))

Comment: thanks, but can you give me some code to execute the user's code in the create view? The code should execute in the run view, giving the result. Could you give me some code for that? Thanks!